# Define a Constructor<T> to require specific arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a situation where I have a `PropertiesObject` or `Structure` of an instance of a class that needs to then be converted to an actual instance at runtime by a function that takes the `Constructor` and `Structure` as arguments. But it allows me to pass in a constructor that does not adhere to the signature. See below:

```
  type PropertyNames<T> = {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
  }[keyof T];

  type Struct<T> = Pick<T, PropertyNames<T>>;

  type Constructor<T> = new (struct: Struct<T>) => T;


  class MagicMonkey {
    age: number;
    name: string;

    fly() {

    }
  }

  function createObjectIntance<T>(Constructor: Constructor<T>, struct: Struct<T>): T {
    return new Constructor(struct);
  }

  const jack: MagicMonkey = createObjectIntance(MagicMonkey, { name: 'jack', age: 1000})

  console.log(jack)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATAuE8AcFNgBQE4HsYIgOQIYFtoGcAeAFQD5gBeYAbwCgR7gBtAaWAEsA7YAa2nCQBmwIgF0AXMJYjg0AB6hoHACZ5gAMQCuHAMag2SLgH5gHaADdoCYBOYBuOsAC+jXvyGj7DiDGABlUAgausRklHBs2tzEADTwyKgYOPghJJ4g3rAAwgZ4AUGgSAghFCbQAO7AABS5gboS-rWgIQCUFGREng7aADaYeKoAspgA5hEDBq7UDiAj0BIcGtgARpb2DBxJEjWcw2n0At3gla20004OjjQOAlq6+lzaCNCYCgDySwBW0LoAkhygmB00BClWyHBq+UKEjBEN0hRCsVhoHqeWCpGaEiIUwYT1AGgQXFMFRhqIKCGqpOaa3OXRyoGAH0wkQkQ1G2nGHEmlEezzen2+oD+AKBlVZYwmfFiVBMm2AAHJGZE5bFZhIAIwABi1jmaVxA2hySG60AAdN0kMNKoruLqgA)

`MagicMonkey` doesn't have a constructor that takes an argument of `Struct<MagicMonkey>`. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

It does force me to write `new Constructor(struct);` and not just `new Constructor();` inside the function. So it's working to some extent.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters - note that it has a constructor without parameters.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks, from that it's clear it's not a bug. And it makes sense now that I think of it. There is no guarantee that if `MagicMonkey` had a `contructor(age: number, name: string)` that it would do anything with the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're typing `createObjectInstance` to accept an object with non-function property names of the class. Not an array of constructor arguments.

Type of `MagicMonkey` constructor is `() => MagicMonkey`. Type the `createObjectInstance` is expecting as the first agrument is `{ new (struct: Struct<MagicMonkey>): MagicMonkey }`. And they are perfectly assignable:

```ts
declare const mNoArgs: { new (): MagicMonkey }

const mStruct: { new (struct: Struct<MagicMonkey>): MagicMonkey } = mNoArgs // no error
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w623ew)

It might help to grasp the general idea of that assignment being completely type safe if you think about source function as a function that simply discards any arguments it may get and returns exactly the type we need.

If you want to type `createObjectInstance` so that the constructor should reject incompatible arguments you should make something like:

```ts
function createObjectIntance<
    T, 
    Args extends unknown[]
>(ctor: { new (...args: [...Args]): T }, ...args: [...Args]): T {
  return new ctor(...args)
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5qJw)

Comment: Thanks,  I believe I understand.